# Como ejecutar expresión regular en evento Keyup con JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Tengo esta expresion regular que valida hasta 10 enteros un punto decimal y hasta 10 decimales,¿Como puedo implementar esta expresion regular en un textbox para que si no se cumple la validacion me marque un error
o me detenga la escritura

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#decimalEntero').on('input', function (e) {
    if (/^(\d{1,10})(.\d{1,10})?$/i.test(this.value)) {
        alert("Ok"); 
    }else{
        alert("error");
    }
});
});
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>10 Enteros + 10 decimales</title> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#">
<p>
<input type="text" name="valor" id="decimalEntero" /><br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar HTML5 y los eventos oninvalid y oninput y sin necesidad de utilizar JavaScript.

OJO: Si quieres utilizar esto en un formulario que ingresa datos en una base de datos, no olvides validar también utilizando un script del lado del servidor (server-side scripting).

```html
<form action="#">
<p>
<input type="text" name="valor" id="decimalEntero" pattern="(\d{1,10})(.\d{1,10})?" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('No es válido')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" /><br />
</form>
```